# Broadcast REST API call to all instances in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a Docker container that is REST API webserver.  I want to use this webserver in a Docker Swarm, and there will be no connections between the webserver instances. One of the REST API calls is use to update the webserver (provide it with new data).  How can I broadcast this REST API call to all instances in the Docker Swarm to ensure each and every instance has the same data?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "there will be no connections between the webserver instances"? Could you provide more information on your expected architecture? E.g. "each and every instance" of what? Do you mean you want to deploy multiple instances of the webserver as multiple containers which should sync their data between each other?

Comment: Each Docker container will be independent  from every other container.  Each container will be a member of the Docker Swarm cluster, and will contain a REST API webserver.  There will be no sharing of data between the containers.  Is there a way to "sync" the data between each container using the REST API I have defined?

Comment: Please make an example like: "I have a base image/Dockerfile which describes how to build my webserver. From this image I'm deriving two containers: C1 and C2. If the webserver from C1 receives new data through its REST API, C2 should update its data accordingly". If you updated your question, please also include information about: Which component is responsible for storing the data? A database? If yes, is it part of one of the base image? But in the and my real question is: What has docker to do with updating your application across multiple containers?

Comment: The Swarm service will be a single container (self-contained - no database), that will receive uploaded data from a REST API call.  It will store the data within the container for future use (other REST API calls).  The Swarm will have multiple instances of this service running, so I am looking for a way to propagate the same data to all service instances within the the Swarm.  I would like to do that through Docker, perhaps iterate the list of all instances and make the same REST API, but I would prefer that the API caller not have to do this iteration - that is happens automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

You define one stateful service (webserver) which should be replicated ending in multiple tasks. A client (e.g. using a browser) is able to modify the state of the webserver using a REST API. As the client does only connect to one of the tasks, the other tasks get out of sync. Now you want to know how to keep all tasks in sync.

**Answer**

Docker swarm is currently not build for stateful services, so there is no API provided by Docker to solve your problem (right now). But they seam to be aware of the problem, which is probably why Docker [acquired Infinit](https://blog.docker.com/2016/12/docker-acquires-infinit/) a company which builds a scalable, distributed storage system.

With this in mind, you could give Infinit a chance and probably relying on something which gets integrated into Docker anyway or at least very simple.

Possible further solutions:

- [Flocker](https://github.com/ScatterHQ/flocker)
- [Minio](https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-docker-quickstart-guide)
- [Resilio](https://www.resilio.com/blog/official-bittorrent-sync-docker-recipe)
- [REX-Ray](https://rexray.thecodeteam.com/#get-started)
- [vSpehre](https://blogs.vmware.com/virtualblocks/2017/04/10/orchestrate-stateful-containers-using-docker-swarm-vsphere-docker-volume-service/)

And of course you can use any other traditional NFS/DFS solution to sync the data between the tasks. Or even consider to abstract the storage completely into only one database container.

Further reading:

- [forums.docker.com - Stateful containers](https://forums.docker.com/t/stateful-containers/31212/3)